# WCF Client CloseAsync vs Abort()

Tags: wcf

I'm using Portable Class Libraries to build service classes that all our UI technology with use to communicate with our services.

These libraries will support Silverlight, Asp.Net and any other .Net UI technology.

Since Silverlight is supported, all calls must be asynchronous.

With Silverlight, I can call CloseAsync() immediately after client.Method() call to the service.

However, I'm finding that doesn't work with Asp.Net clients.

I don't want to use CloseAync() in the completed code because if multiple async calls are being made you could run into a timing issue.

I'd rather not have to come up with a lot of logic something like putting a while loop in every async method to make sure CloseAsync() hasn't been called and completed.

Right now I'm testing just using Abort in the completed sections and everything appears to be working fine.

Just curious if anybody else out there knows of any problems we may run into Using Abort?

Thanks.

We're using .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which binding you're using. If you're using a binding which uses sessions, then calling Close[Async] will attempt to first close that session (e.g., WSHttpBinding with reliable messaging), then close the connection, otherwise it will remain alive in the server side until it times out. If you're using a binding which does not use sessions (i.e., BasicHttpBinding), then they're pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The classes will be written to support any binding the user decides.  We may have a custom binary for a silverlight client, net.tcp for a WPF client etc.  Which is used will be based on a value passed into an Initialize function.

Comment: In looking at the states, it appears the state goes into closing immediately after the CloseAsync call.  So for now, in my initialize, I instantiate a new client if the state isn't Open or Created.  In the completed code, I use abort if state is Faulted and CloseAsync() otherwise.  So far this appears to be working for both Silverlight & asp.net clients.

Comment: As far as the client is concerned, it will work just fine. But if you have a low max session quota in the server, it's possible that it may be hit (i.e., new clients may get denied a new session). This will only happen if you have a very large traffic for sessionful endpoints, so it may not be a problem for you.